# Why is the new string not being printed after adding char characters?

Tags: c, char, cs50, c-strings, function-definition

I'm stating to write some leetspeak code in C, however, I keep getting error like:

```
error: incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'char' from a function with result type 'string' (aka 'char *') [-werror,-wint-conversion]
```

or simply my latest code is not returning any value.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

string replace(string no_vowels);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error message\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("This is your message: %s\n", replace(argv[1]));
    }
}

string replace(string no_vowels)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (no_vowels[i] != '\0')
    {
        i++;
    }

    string subs = "6310";
    string new_string = "";

    for (int l = 0; l < i; l++)
    {
        if (no_vowels[l] == 'a')
        {
            new_string += subs[0];
        }
        else if (no_vowels[l] == 'e')
        {
            new_string += subs[1];
        }
        else if (no_vowels[l] == 'i')
        {
            new_string += subs[2];
        }
        else if (no_vowels[l] == 'o')
        {
            new_string += subs[3];
        }
        new_string += no_vowels[l];
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

I tried creating arrays with the numbers that should substitute the letters directly, tried to add or subtract values taking in consideration each char character on the ASCII table and looked for existing threads on StackOverflow

PS: I am trying to do this exercise with the libraries that are already imported.

Comment: This isn't how strings work in C at all.

Comment: There's a common problem which makes me unlike CS50, and your code exhibits that problem: `string` isn't a real type. It's an alias for `char *`. So `string new_string = "";` is the same as `char *new_string = "";`. It's a pointer, and it points to the empty string, which is read-only. You can't modify the string that `new_string` is pointing to. But it's even worse, because `new_string += ...` will change the pointer, so it points somewhere else, it doesn't modify the string itself. So there's two errors for the price of one.

Comment: You can't concatenate strings in C with things like `new_string += subs[0];`. You'll need to use something like `strcat()` and ensure you've allocated enough space for your final string. Aside: `l` is a terrible name for a variable, as it looks very like `1`.

Comment: This is why CS50's definition of `string` is absolutely infuriating. It hides what C is doing, and creates a ton of confusion, all for zero benefit, not even saved keystrokes.

Comment: Avoid using `l` (lowercase-L) as a variable name, almost indistinguishable from `1` (one) in many fonts.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot concatenate strings in C using `+=` as you would in javascript. For this assignment, you could modify the argument string in place and return the original pointer.

Here is a modified version:

```
string replace(string no_vowels)
{
    string subs = "6310";

    for (int i = 0; no_vowels[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (no_vowels[i] == 'a')
        {
            no_vowels[i] = subs[0];
        }
        else if (no_vowels[i] == 'e')
        {
            no_vowels[i] = subs[1];
        }
        else if (no_vowels[i] == 'i')
        {
            no_vowels[i] = subs[2];
        }
        else if (no_vowels[i] == 'o')
        {
            no_vowels[i] = subs[3];
        }
    }
    return no_vowels;
}
```

Note also that the purpose of the `string` typedef in the CS50 course is to hide the implementation and avoid *pointer shock* for C newbies.  It is like trailing wheels for small kids, you should very quickly remove them and learn the real skills.

Here is a modified version with the actual types:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *replace(char *str);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Invalid argument count\n");
        return 1;
    } else {
        printf("This is your message: %s\n", replace(argv[1]));
        return 0;
    }
}

// replace vowels in place in the argument string
char *replace(char *str) {
    const char *subs = "6310";

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (str[i] == 'a') {
            str[i] = subs[0];
        } else
        if (str[i] == 'e') {
            str[i] = subs[1];
        } else
        if (str[i] == 'i') {
            str[i] = subs[2];
        } else
        if (str[i] == 'o') {
            str[i] = subs[3];
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Here are alternative implementations you can study:

Using a `switch` statement:

```
char *replace(char *str) {
    const char *subs = "6310";

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        switch (str[i]) {
          case 'a':
            str[i] = subs[0];
            break;
          case 'e':
            str[i] = subs[1];
            break;
          case 'i':
            str[i] = subs[2];
            break;
          case 'o':
            str[i] = subs[3];
            break;
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Using `memchr` from `<string.h>`:

```
#include <string.h>

char *replace(char *str) {
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        const char *p = memchr("aeio6310", str[i], 4);
        if (p != NULL) {
            str[i] = p[4];
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: From the OP's code, it looks like `replace` is meant to be non-destructive to the original string. Note that this would be destructive.

Comment: @Chris: yes and another gotcha is *is it allowed to modify the contents of the strings pointed to by `argv[...]`?  The OP's code did not modify the argument string, which is a given in other languages where `string` objects are immutable, but it is unclear whether this is mandated in the assignment.

Comment: "is it allowed to modify the contents of the strings pointed to by argv[...]" --> Yes.  "The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program ..."

Comment: This (and the OP code) is screaming for a `switch( str[i] )` in place of the if-else if chain.

Comment: @Clifford: I added food for thought for the OP.  `switch` might not have been studied yet...

Comment: re switch, Understood.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm going to assume based on your code that you're not meant to modify the input string, but rather return a new string with the modified contents.*

C strings are lower level than strings in something like Python. A C string is an array of characters then length of the string plus one for  null terminator (`'\0'`).

You need to create such an array for `new_string`. Fortunately, you know the length, since your program doesn't change the length of the original string. You can allocate a new string, copy into it following your replacement logic, then return the new string.

A first naive attempt at this might look like:

```
char * replace(const char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char new_string[len + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len + 1; i++) {
        // assign new_string[i] from str[i] as appropriate
    }

    // Assign the null terminator.
    new_string[len] = '\0';

    // Returning a pointer to the local variable,
    // see note below about "undefined behavior."
    return new_string;
}
```

Except C has another gotcha. The pointer you're returning might still point to that array, or it might not. By returning a pointer to a local variable from a function, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior). Keep in mind that undefined behavior does not necessarily mean your program will fail. It means it could fail. It could continue but do something you didn't expect. *It could also work the way you expect.* This is especially dangerous as it can lead you to have unrealistic expectations for what comprises "good code."

To avoid this, you need to *dynamically allocate* that new string so that the memory "outlives" the function call. You'll also want to check the return of `malloc` before using that memory, in case it didn't work and didn't allocate you the memory you were expecting.

```
char * replace(const char *str) {
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *new_string = malloc(len + 1);
    if (new_string == NULL) return NULL;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len + 1; i++) {
        // assign new_string[i] from str[i] as appropriate
    }

    // Assign the null terminator.
    new_string[len] = '\0';

    return new_string;
}
```

You should also remember to `free` the dynamically allocated memory in `main`. This means you need to hang onto a pointer to it, so you cannot use it directly in your call to `printf`. This also gives you an opportunity to determine that the memory allocation for the new string succeeded.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Error message\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    char *replacement = replace(argv[1]);
    
    if (replacement == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("This is your message: %s\n", replacement);
    free(replacement);
}
```

Comment: You could use `strdup()`, now included in the upcoming C23 Standard. Also `i < len + 1` -> `i < len`

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, definitely.

Comment: Also hint that the `string` returned by `replace` should be freed... which is a concept that is not yet mastered at this level in the CS50 course, not to mention the fact that `string` objects returned by `get_string()` are managed transparently and need not be freed manually.  I'm not sure if hiding the gory details from the beginners is helping them in the long run or teaches them bad habits or erroneous concepts that will cause even more confusion.

Comment: Chris, `return new_string;` in first `replace()` also deserves a comment **in code** about UB.  Later words about UB are easily missed.

Comment: Starting with  a counter-example demonstrating an error the OP has not actually made is probably a bad idea.  The casual reader may not even know it is a counter-example, since you only make that clear after the fact.  Moreover,  internally allocating and returning a string is also a bad idea in most cases, asking for a memory leak. Also most of this question addresses your assumption that the modify-in-place was not itself intentional, which is probably an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Your function definition is invalid.

In this line

```
string new_string = "";
```

you declared a pointer to a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

In statements like that

```
new_string += subs[0];
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic that changes the pointer `new_string` itself. As a result the pointer has an invalid value that does not point to a valid object declared in the function. And if to assume that such statements are rewritten correctly nevertheless this statement

```
new_string += no_vowels[l];
```

is in any case wrong because logically you are trying to overwrite already updated character in if-else statements.

This while loop

```
while (no_vowels[i] != '\0')
{
    i++;
}
```

is redundant. Strings are ended with the terminating zero character `'\0'`. So you can use this fact creating a condition of a loop for travesing a string. In any case the variables `i` and `l` should have the unsigned type `size_t` instead of the signed type `int`.

As far as I know the letter `'u'` is also a vowel. However you are ignoring it together with upper case vowels.

There is no need to create a new string. According to the C Standard you may change program parameters pointed to ponters `argv`.

From the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup)

> 2. — The parameters argc and argv and **the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable** by the program, and retain their
>    last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

The function can look the following way

```
string replace( string no_vowels )
{
    string subs = "6310";

    for ( char *p = no_vowels; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p == 'a' )
        {
            *p = subs[0];
        }
        else if ( *p == 'e' )
        {
            *p = subs[1];
        }
        else if ( *p == 'i' )
        {
            *p = subs[2];
        }
        else if ( *p == 'o' )
        {
            *p = subs[3];
        }
    }

    return no_vowels;
}
```